# Having a Token Error when creating PowerQuery

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, data-cleaning

This sub creates a powerquery with the source from a folderpath, it gets all the excel files from the folder and consolidate and filter it.

I am having an error whenever I make Source = Folder.Files("Dir") dynamic
Is there a way to make the paths dynamic so that I will just refresh the query page and update the value of the SourcePath for Folder.Files in my Settings sheet.

I have this error

> Runtime-error '1004':
> [Expression.Error] The name 'Source' wasn't recognized, Make sure it's spelled correctly.

in this line `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False`

If I create a value for SourcePath referencing a cell in a sheet with this format `"C:\Path"` ,It has this error

> Error:
> Runtime Error '1004':
> Application Defined or Object-defined error

in this line
`.ListObject.DisplayName = "Data"`

```
Sub AddSaveQuery()
'Set Objects
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim SavePath As String
SourcePath = Worksheets("Home").Range("G21").Value
SavePath = Worksheets("Home").Range("G8").Value
Sub AddSaveQuery()
'Set Objects 
Dim SourcePath As String 
Dim SavePath As String 

SourcePath = Worksheets("Home").Range("G21").Value 
SavePath = Worksheets("Home").Range("G8").Value

'Will set first condition for sheet2
'Filter Column2 Begins with FilterValue1
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Data", Formula:= _
                           "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""" &     SourcePath & """)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Hidden Files1"" = Table.SelectRows(Source, Each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Invoke Custom Function1"" = Table.AddColumn(#""Filtered Hidden Files1"", ""Transform File"", Each #""Transform File""([Content]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns1""" & _
                           " = Table.RenameColumns(#""Invoke Custom Function1"", {""Name"", ""Source.Name""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Other Columns1"" = Table.SelectColumns(#""Renamed Columns1"", {""Source.Name"", ""Transform File""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Table Column1"" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#""Removed Other Columns1"", ""Transform File"", Table.ColumnNames(#""Transform File""(#""Sample File"")))," & Chr(13) & "" & _
                           "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Expanded Table Column1"",{{""Source.Name"", Type text}, {""Column1"", Type any}, {""Column2"", Type any})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Removed Other Columns"" = Table.SelectColumns(#""Column1" & _
                           "ed Type"",{""Column2""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.Sel" & _
                           "ectRows(#""Removed Other Columns"", Each Text.StartsWith([Column2], ""FilterValue1""))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Parameter1", Formula:= _
                           "#""Sample File"" meta [IsParameterQuery=true, BinaryIdentifier=#""Sample File"", Type=""Binary"", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]"
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Transform Sample File", Formula:= _
                           "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(Parameter1, null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Page1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Page1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"""
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sample File", Formula:= _
                           "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""" & SourcePath & """)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Navigation1 = Source{0}[Content]" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Navigation1"
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Transform File", Formula:= _
                           "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = (Parameter1) => let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        Source = Excel.Workbook(Parameter1, null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        Page1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Page1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "        #""Promoted Headers""" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
     "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Data;Extended Properties=""""" _
     , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Data]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Data"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Workbooks("CognosDataCleaner2.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Parameter1", _
                                                      "Connection To the        'Parameter1' query in the workbook.", _
                                                      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Parameter1;Extended Properties=""""" _
                                                      , "SELECT * FROM [Parameter1]", 2
Workbooks("CognosDataCleaner2.xlsm").Connections.Add2 _
                                                      "Query - Transform Sample File", _
                                                      "Connection To the        'Transform Sample File' query in the workbook.", _
                                                      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Transform Sample File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                                      , "SELECT * FROM [Transform Sample File]", 2
Workbooks("CognosDataCleaner2.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Sample File", _
                                                      "Connection To the        'Sample File' query in the workbook.", _
                                                      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Sample File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                                      , "SELECT * FROM [Sample File]", 2
Workbooks("CognosDataCleaner2.xlsm").Connections.Add2 "Query - Transform File" _
                                                      , "Connection To the        'Transform File' query in the workbook.", _
                                                      "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Transform File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                                      , "SELECT * FROM [Transform File]", 2

'Rename New Query Sheet to TEST1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "TEST1"
Sheets("TEST1").Select


Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Transform File", _
                                    "Connection To the        'Transform File' query in the     workbook.", _
                                    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Transform File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                    , "SELECT * FROM [Transform File]", 2
Workbooks("Book1").Connections.Add2 "Query - Sample File", _
                                    "Connection To the        'Sample File' query in the workbook.", _
                                    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Sample File"";Extended Properties=""""" _
                                    , "SELECT * FROM [Sample File]", 2
Sheets("TEST1").Copy

'SAVE PATH
ChDir SavePath
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                      SavePath _
                      , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

I have created an Object SourcePath and in that path I concat it so it does have the value like this:
"Directory"

> A1 = "
> A2 = "
> A3 = Directory or path
>
> =CONCAT(A1 & A3 & A2)

I also have set Source as String to make it an object aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes round the path, so:

```
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Folder.Files(""" &     SourcePath & """),"
```